# How to detect largest rectangle in a grid using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have some images which are in form of a grid. I have a code that works to find the largest rectangle in the grid. However it works in some images and completely fails in doing so in others, I need help fine-tuning the code to work in all the cases. Ideally I'd like the contours exactly on the border.

The code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img =  cv2.imread('3.jpg')
frame = cv2.resize(img,(1000,500))

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_red = np.array([0, 10, 120])
upper_red = np.array([15, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange (hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
cv2.imshow("a",mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(),
                           cv2.RETR_TREE,
                           cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
if len(contours) > 0:
    red_area = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(red_area)
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(x, y),(x+w, y+h),(0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Image in which it works correctly:

[image: Original Image]

[image: Edges]

[image: Detected Rectangle]

Image in which the code does not work:

[image: Original]

[image: Edges]

[image: Detected Rectangle]

Comment: If all of the images are like that (black graph, light red background), you might want to just amplify the contrast of the image before the HSV masking?

Comment: @ArohanAjit the expected output is the whole ECG graph without the surrounding text??

Comment: @AKX I did as u suggested, I think the problem is that the gridlines for inner image is much more highlighted than the border ones, so the code detects only brightest part of inner gridlines as opposed to the entire rectangle.

Comment: Yes @Bilal that is the expected output, only the the ecg graph area, nothing extraneous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem in **finding the max contour after thresolding** can be solved simply by identifying the max contour corners:

[image: solution]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img =  cv2.imread('2.png')
frame = cv2.resize(img,(1000,500))

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_red = np.array([0, 10, 120])
upper_red = np.array([15, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange (hsv, lower_red, upper_red)


y0 = np.min(np.where(mask>0)[0])
x0 = np.min(np.where(mask>0)[1])

y1 = np.max(np.where(mask>0)[0])
x1 = np.max(np.where(mask>0)[1])

cv2.rectangle(frame,(x0, y0),(x1, y1),(0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```